# A different set of terms for each group?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, group

I am considering to use de group-module to organize nodes by department. Each department has different taxonomy terms to classify their nodes. The goal is to have them describe their howto's and workflows, classified by task. (Drupal 8)

The setup:
Group Type = department
Groups of type department: Sales, Buying, Finance
Node type: Article with fields (title, body, etc) and a taxonomy-reference named "tasks"

example: Sales has tasks like "prepare quote", while Finance has tasks like "prepare sales invoice" - each have their own set of tasks they want to refer to.
Both would use the content type "Article".

**Question:** How would I organize the vocabulary "tasks" to show the relevant terms to the user of a department when they are editing or creating a new Article ?

Comment: The Group module ships with gnode - allowing for nodes to be associated with groups. There is a patch for gmedia - allowing media to be associated with groups. You could probably follow the methods used for those two entity types and create your own plugin for taxonomy terms. You will then have to add your own logic to add the taxonomy terms to the groups though - upon save you'll need to loop through and create the association. (Note - speculation based on integrating different entity types with groups).

Comment: Or I could create a Group Type for each department (with then only one group in it).

Comment: I don’t see how that would solve your taxonomy question.

Comment: Each Group Type would have its own Vocabulary and each Group Type would have only 1 group in it. I would have a Vocabulary with tasks that Sales persons do, another with the tasks of a Finance person.